# Non ASCII character in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, utf-8, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I have a MVC 2 application. `<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>` is added in web.config and `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` in master page.  But the Non-ASCII characters still can not be encoded and decoded correctly.

For example, "Mayagüez" is displayed in an action, but after passed through a url, it is displayed as "Mayag�ez".

If I try to use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode for "Mayagüez", the string is truncated as "Mayag" after processed through HttpUtility.HtmlDecode.

Comment: You need to show code you have problem with - small sample that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out that using Url.Encode instead of HttpUtility.HtmlEncode can make it work.